# In google cloud, I am getting this error while using the command "terraform apply"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp

In google cloud, i am getting this error while performing the lab of automating the deployment using terraform?

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.

Please help me out of this issue?

Comment: This is not an error. That is just an information.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution of this problem
Instead of the command `terraform plan` we should use  `terraform plan -out tfplan` command to apply the change to our terraform file.
I hope this solution help you out from this problem